# How to run Inferno JSX on server?

Tags: babeljs, jsx, server-side-rendering, infernojs

I am trying to use [Inferno](https://infernojs.org/) to render on the server. The documentation [inferno-server](https://infernojs.org/docs/api/inferno-server) and [server-side-rendering](https://infernojs.org/docs/guides/server-side-rendering) does **not** say show to set-up babel & run the sever.

All I could find is [InfernoJS Babel Plugin](https://github.com/infernojs/babel-plugin-inferno) but noting about running it on Node.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what you mean by "Running on node"?
Inferno Babel plugin converts the JSX code into a regular JS code, which runs without problems on node (the server uses renderToString). While you are not using browser elements (document and other tools), everything should be fine.
Then you need to make a separate component for the client, which when requested will be given as a bundle along with the html page, and then using **hydrate** function to "cling" into webpage and bind items.

you can check my repository (although this is for TypeScript): https://github.com/MrFoxPro/inferno-isomorphic-tempalte